# Android Studio Doesn't Show Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I just downloaded Android Studio and just when I thought I was done, I bumped into a few issues.
• 1 - My AVD doesn't show on Android Studio
• 2 - I'm unable to create an emulator on the AVD manager and AS.

If anyone has any idea on what's causing this issues, please kindly assist a brother in need.

Comment: What error is it showing ? can you share your screen shot.

Answer (score 1):

you can download genymotion from web and work with it.it works actually better and faster than the built-in AVD  nexus in android studio.